# Bulk formula replace / Dynamic reference in the Find/Replace function

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have about a hundred cells with a formula 
=getPivotData(...)

I want to replace all of them with =ifError(getPivotData(...),0)

Find & Replace does not seem do the trick. Or at least I have failed to locate a method to use original value in the replacement text.

Doing in parts, i.e. replace =getPivotData with =ifError(getPivotData first and then replace ) with ),0) fails due to "formula contains an error" message.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a more *orthodox* way of doing what you ask, but I think you can try replacing the '=' with some unique text, so Excel doesn't expect it to be a formula. Of course this text shouldn't be found in any other cell. For example, "@@@". So you first replace `=getPivotData` With `@@@ifError(getPivotData`, then `)` with `),0)` (*see note*) and finally `@@@` with `=`.

*Note: make sure you are not finding hundreds of `)` which are not the end of the formula!!*